# How do I use .prt files in R?

Tags: r, file-format

I am trying to use climate data for analysis using R code. However, I came across a data format for which I cannot find any documentation.

The ***.prt*** extension is used for many applications but I believe mine is a **Printer-formatted file**.

It has no proper delimiters and it cannot be processed by any other application but I can easily view it in a text editor. Because of the nature of the climate data, processing it in C or Python would be very cumbersome.

Kindly help me to read this file into R or to convert it to a file format readable in R.

EDIT:

The data in the prt file is in the format below. As you can see, it follows a map of India with no proper format or delimiters. Each file consists of certain climate values for each day of the year. I have 53 such files.:

```
  Day= 1-Jan
       66.5E 67.5E 68.5E 69.5E 70.5E 71.5E 72.5E 73.5E 74.5E 75.5E 76.5E 77.5E 78.5E 79.5E 80.5E 81.5E 82.5E 83.5E 84.5E 85.5E 86.5E 87.5E 88.5E 89.5E 90.5E 91.5E 92.5E 93.5E 94.5E 95.5E 96.5E 97.5E
 37.5N                                                                                                                                                                                                
 36.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0   0.0                                                                                                            
 35.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                      
 34.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                            
 33.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                            
 32.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                            
 31.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                            
 30.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                      
 29.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                 0.0   0.0   0.0      
 28.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  12.0   8.8                                       0.0               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 27.5N                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 26.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0            
 25.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                  
 24.5N               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                  
 23.5N               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0   0.0   0.0                        
 22.5N                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                     0.0                              
 21.5N                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                      
 20.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                  
 19.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                        
 18.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                              
 17.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                    
 16.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                          
 15.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                      
 14.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                      
 13.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                      
 12.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   1.4                                                                                                      
 11.5N                                                         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.5                                                                                                            
 10.5N                                                         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                            
  9.5N                                                               0.0   0.0   0.0   2.4                                                                                                            
  8.5N                                                               0.0   0.3   2.5                                                                                                                  

  Day= 2-Jan
```

I've tried the method suggested in the comments and this is the output I received. But this is not the output I require. I need each of the values under the latitude-longitude to be separate, not as part of an array element.

```
> 
[1] "  Day= 1-Jan"                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [2] "       66.5E 67.5E 68.5E 69.5E 70.5E 71.5E 72.5E 73.5E 74.5E 75.5E 76.5E 77.5E 78.5E 79.5E 80.5E 81.5E 82.5E 83.5E 84.5E 85.5E 86.5E 87.5E 88.5E 89.5E 90.5E 91.5E 92.5E 93.5E 94.5E 95.5E 96.5E 97.5E"
 [3] " 37.5N                                                                                                                                                                                                "
 [4] " 36.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0   0.0                                                                                                            "
 [5] " 35.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                      "
 [6] " 34.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                            "
 [7] " 33.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                            "
 [8] " 32.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                            "
 [9] " 31.5N                                                   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                            "
[10] " 30.5N                                             0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                                      "
[11] " 29.5N                                       0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                                 0.0   0.0   0.0      "
[12] " 28.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  12.0   8.8                                       0.0               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0"
[13] " 27.5N                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0"
[14] " 26.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0            "
[15] " 25.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0         0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                  "
[16] " 24.5N               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                  "
[17] " 23.5N               0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0               0.0   0.0   0.0                        "
[18] " 22.5N                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                     0.0                              "
[19] " 21.5N                     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                      "
[20] " 20.5N                           0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0                                                                  "
```

Comment: since you can read it as text, why don't you try to import it in R with a standard function `readLines()` or `scan()`? If you get stuck, come back with a reproducible example, including an extract of that data. It's impossible to help otherwise, with the info you've provided.

Comment: we can't possibly help with this question without more information -- a sample of what a `.prt` file looks like, or a pointer to more information.

Comment: @baptiste I have provided the information as requested. I have tried the readLines() as well as the scan() function, to no avail. I need the data in a matrix format as represented in the file itself. But accessing this data is really difficult.

Comment: @BenBolker I hope the information provided is sufficient to understand the nature of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your data format is quite irregular. I wasn't sure if you just had one date in each file or if there were multiple (your example seems to have a second day starting at the bottom). But assuming the latter (which should work for the first scenario as well) here's one strategy using `readLines()` to just get the data in, then extracting the data of interest with `read.fwf`

```
lines <- readLines("test.prt")
days <- grep("Day=", xx)

outlist <- lapply(days, function(day){
    headers <- strsplit(gsub("^\\s+","",lines[day+1])," ")[[1]]
    date <- gsub(".*Day= ", "", lines[day], perl=T)
    con <- textConnection(lines[day:(day+30)+1])
    dd <- read.fwf(con, widths=rep(6, 33), header=F, skip=1)
    names(dd) <- c("lat", headers)
    close(con)
    dd<-reshape(dd, idvar="lat", ids="lat",
        times=names(dd)[-1], timevar="lon", 
        varying=list(names(dd)[-1]), v.names="obs",
        direction="long")
    dd <- cbind(date=date, dd)
    dd <- subset(dd, !is.na(obs))
    rownames(dd)<-NULL
    dd
})
do.call(rbind, outlist)
```

So we read all the lines in, then find all the "Day=" positions. Then we read the headers from the next line, and then we create a `textConnection()` to read the rest of the data in with `read.fwf()` (which apparently does not have a `text=` parameter). Next, I reshape the data so that you get one row for each lat/lon. I chose to also merge in the data from the section header and to remove the missing values. Finally, after I have a data.frame for each list, I `rbind` all the data together. The results look like this

```
   date    lat   lon obs
1 1-Jan  24.5N 68.5E   0
2 1-Jan  23.5N 68.5E   0
3 1-Jan  27.5N 69.5E   0
4 1-Jan  24.5N 69.5E   0
5 1-Jan  23.5N 69.5E   0
6 1-Jan  22.5N 69.5E   0
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. You are correct. I have 365 days in each file. I ran the code you gave me and although it works beautifully for one date, it throws up lots of errors for more than one date.

The main error I found was this:
``Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(d[, idvar], times[1L],  :    duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed``

Kindly help if you can. I am completely new to R. I have barely even used it for more than a week.

Comment: @GaidinD I've updated the code to better handle multiple dates per file. Please try it again.

Comment: Thanks. This worked amazingly. Now all I got to do is access the data in the data frames. Thank you so much. You have no idea how much you have helped me.